# C Shared memory database

Tags: c, database, memory, shared

So this is a homework assignment, and it's kind of a doozy so i'll try to TL;DR it. Basically Im making a Shared memory database with 5 files (load,query,clean,print,change)
Load loads the database from a file. (students have a first name/last name/address/telephone number)
Query lets someone "search" for a specific student
print....well prints the contents of the shared memory
and change lets people change the database
and clean gets rid of the sephamores and saves the contents of the shared memory to a file.

Now the professor gave us a bunch of code, and for the most part I understand it. His was seperated in 3 files. (a change,create and header file)
My main question is, how would I go about storing multiple "objects" into shared memory.

Like he keeps the student data in a struct naturally, and for his "example" he seems to load it by using a struct * ptr. But how would I go about loading multiple students?

I could post the source here, but it's 4 different files and quite long.

Comment: If I answer your question will you give me your diploma after you graduate? I've always wanted a second degree :-)

Comment: I remember that project ... how's CS470G? And Dr. Mani?

Comment: Yup thats him, he's good. And Im not looking for "the code" I just mainly wanted to know how the store multiple students, but I guess using an array of structs would work fine. Do you remember if the project ended up being very long/hard? He gave us quite a bit of sample code that I've been looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of structs, instead of a single struct?

Comment: This.  Unless you need it to scale dynamically.

Comment: Ya I suppose that makes sense! i didn't know if that worked with shared memory but I guess why not.